# Parameter function in Solidity

Tags: solidity, contract-development, arrays, memory, bytes

I am a newbie in Solidity. Below is the snippet of code I came across :-

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0; contract C {                                           //1
    function f(uint len) {                 // value passed to len = 7          //2 
        uint[] memory a = new uint[](7);                                       //3
        bytes memory b = new bytes(len);                                       //4    
// Here we have a.length == 7 and b.length == len a[6] = 8;                     // 5    
}
}
```

I am unable to understand why (7) is written after `new uint[]` in RHS of line 3. Moreover bytes is a data type of fixed length i.e bytes1 , then how  did they created a new instance  of it with length equal to `len` .  At last what is meant by this `b.length == len a[6] = 8` in line 5 .

Comment: uint[] memory a = new uint[](7); // This Is just another way to define fixed arrays

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am unable to understand why (7) is written after new unit[]

This Is just another way to define fixed arrays.

> Moreover bytes is a data type of fixed length i.e bytes1

From my experience and with the help of this [article](https://betterprogramming.pub/solidity-tutorial-all-about-conversion-661130eb8bec)
I can say that bytes can be of various lengths. And the `len` will be the user input.

> b.length == len a[6] = 8

I think this comment is written wrong, it should've been something like this:

```
b.length == len,  a[6] = 8
```

A comma `,` is missing I think.
If we put the comma then it makes more sense.
So now it just means that b's array length will be equal to `len` which will be the input.

I hope you'll find this helpful